# How to handle Access Denied properly in Vaadin 14 LTS

Tags: spring-boot, java-11, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I started implementing authentication and authorization for our applications written in `Spring Boot (2.2.6.RELEASE)` and `Vaadin 14 LTS (14.6.1)`.

I have followed those resources:

- [Securing your app with Spring Security](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security)
- [Router Exception Handling](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-routing-exception-handling/#rerouting-to-an-error-view)

I have code for checking whether logged-in user has access rights to specified resources implemented in `beforeEnter` method. The problem is with invocation of `event.rerouteToError(AccessDeniedException.class);`. It tries to create an instance of the specified exception with reflection but fails because it does not contain public no-arg constructor.

```java
private void beforeEnter(final BeforeEnterEvent event) {
    if (!AuthView.class.equals(event.getNavigationTarget()) && !AuthUtils.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        event.rerouteTo(AuthView.class);
    }

    if (!AuthUtils.isAccessGranted(event.getNavigationTarget())) {
        event.rerouteToError(AccessDeniedException.class);
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create an instance of 'org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException'. Make sure the class has a public no-arg constructor.
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.ReflectTools.createProxyInstance(ReflectTools.java:519)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.ReflectTools.createInstance(ReflectTools.java:451)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.BeforeEvent.rerouteToError(BeforeEvent.java:720)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.BeforeEvent.rerouteToError(BeforeEvent.java:704)
```

What can be the best solution for that case? I am thinking about two possible solutions:

1. First instantiate `AccessDeniedException` and then pass it to overloaded method in `BeforeEvent`:  `public void rerouteToError(Exception exception, String customMessage)` which should skip creating exception object by reflection
2. Create dedicated `ErrorView` and use method `public void rerouteTo(Class<? extends Component> routeTargetType, RouteParameters parameters)` of `BeforeEvent`

---

I decided to follow [Leif Åstrand's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2376954/leif-%c3%85strand) answer. I created custom `AccessDeniedException` and appropriate error handler. Here is my implementation. Maybe it will be helpful for someone.

```java
public class AccessDeniedException extends RuntimeException {
    private final int code;

    public AccessDeniedException() {
        super("common.error.403.details");
        this.code = HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

}
```

```java
@Tag(Tag.DIV)
@CssImport(value = "./styles/access-denied-view.css")
@CssImport(value = "./styles/access-denied-box.css", themeFor = "vaadin-details")
public class AccessDeniedExceptionHandler extends VerticalLayout implements HasErrorParameter<AccessDeniedException> {

    private final Details details;

    public AccessDeniedExceptionHandler() {
        setWidthFull();
        setHeight("100vh");
        setPadding(false);
        setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER);
        setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.CENTER);
        setClassName(ComponentConstants.ACCESS_DENIED_VIEW);

        this.details = new Details();
        this.details.setClassName(ComponentConstants.ACCESS_DENIED_BOX);
        this.details.addThemeVariants(DetailsVariant.REVERSE, DetailsVariant.FILLED);
        this.details.setOpened(true);

        add(this.details);
    }

    @Override
    public final int setErrorParameter(final BeforeEnterEvent event, final ErrorParameter<AccessDeniedException> parameter) {
        final int code = parameter.getException().getCode();

        this.details.setSummaryText(getTranslation("common.error.403.header", code));
        this.details.setContent(new Text(getTranslation(parameter.getException().getMessage())));

        return code;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend creating a custom exception type instead of reusing `AccessDeniedException` from Spring. In that way, you don't have to deal with the required error message at all.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your first solution, you could do:

```java
event.rerouteToError(new AccessDeniedException("Navigation target not permitted"), "");
```

- or maybe also specify the `customMessage` if you want. If you see the implementation of the `rerouteToError(Class)` method, it just passes empty `customMessage` and creates the Exception - which you could do manually and that's completely acceptable. **I recommend this solution.**

---

Another solution could be to subclass AccessDeniedException and use that with reflection:

```java
public class RouteAccessDeniedException extends AccessDeniedException {
    public RouteAccessDeniedException() {
        super("Navigation target not permitted");
    }
}
```

I **don't** recommend this solution.